# xampp laravel blank page when using vhost windows

Tags: windows, laravel, xampp

Trying to use xampp for my virtual host on Windows 10. 
But when I open up my project in browser it's a blank page. Not an error message, just blank.

Can anyone help?

Here's my VHosts

```
 # Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:3000>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:3000>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectlara2/public/"
    ServerName projectlara2.test
</VirtualHost>



HERE'S MY Hosts File 

# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1:3000       localhost
#   ::1             localhost


127.0.0.1 localhost projectlara2.test
::1 localhost projectlara2.test
```

Not quite sure what else I'm supposed to write here. It says I have a post that's mostly code so I should add more details but there aren't any more details. Hopefully this is enough extra writing because this is a bit annoying.

Comment: Check your `apache_error.log` file. In wamp it's located under the `logs` directory.

Comment: This is the error.log when I try to run projectlara.test

[Mon Jun 11 20:20:21.241650 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13220:tid 700] AH01909: www.example.com:1443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jun 11 20:20:21.343588 2018] [core:warn] [pid 13220:tid 700] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

Comment: [Mon Jun 11 20:20:21.346907 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 13220:tid 700] AH01909: www.example.com:1443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jun 11 20:20:21.388875 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13220:tid 700] AH00455: Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jun 11 20:20:21.388875 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13220:tid 700] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Mar 28 2018 12:12:41

Comment: [Mon Jun 11 20:20:21.388875 2018] [core:notice] [pid 13220:tid 700] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Jun 11 20:20:21.399864 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13220:tid 700] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10936
[Mon Jun 11 20:20:22.496607 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10936:tid 712] AH01909: www.example.com:1443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: [Mon Jun 11 20:20:22.599651 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10936:tid 712] AH01909: www.example.com:1443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jun 11 20:20:22.652619 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10936:tid 712] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the virtual host properly in your windows host file. You need to just change a little in host file and probably it will solve your error.

change your entry of virtual host in host file from `127.0.0.1 localhost projectlara2.test` to `127.0.0.1     projectlara2.test` and `::1 localhost projectlara2.test` to `::1     projectlara2.test`.

The problem is although you are using virtual host for the project you are declaring localhost with it. Just write the ip and domain name of virtual host, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

On your Windows10 hosts file use this only:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost wiki.com projectlara2.test
```

Then in your vhosts file you can do this:

```
<VirtualHost projectlara2.test:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectlara2/public/"
    ServerName projectlara2.test
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

ServerAdmin, ErrorLog, CustomLog are optional and you can set them up with a real path if you want to, you aren't specifing the server name on your first line on your VirtualHost, when you specify it like this `*:` you are saying that all requests should point to the VirtualHost you are about to define, so if you want more than 1 VirtualHost you should be more specific like I showed. Hope it works! :D

Comment: Should I replace both of these, or just one? 

`<VirtualHost *:3000>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:3000>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName projectlara2.test
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Updating my answer with my own config for your case which might get it working for you

Comment: And yes, that is the root of your problem, * means all requests, so since you have defined `<VirtualHost *:3000> DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" ServerName localhost </VirtualHost>` your others virtualhosts are going to be ignored because you are redirecting ALL(*) requests to /htdocs